# who to store array in database within [{ }] in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to store an array in the database within `[{}]` braces using codeigniter. Now when I store data in array those store like `{}`. I used the following code:

```
$addresses = array();
foreach ($langs as $lang=>$long_name)
{ 
  $addresses[$lang] = $this->input->post('address_'.$lang);
  $meta_search_text .= $titles[$lang].' ';
  $meta_search_text .= $addresses[$lang].' ';
}                   

$data['address'] = json_encode($addresses); //store data in address column
```

Output:

```
{"en":"pune","es":"","ru":"","ar":"","de":"","fr":"","it":"","pt":"","tr":"","hi":"","bn":""}
```

I want it to be like:

```
[{"en":"pune","es":"","ru":"","ar":"","de":"","fr":"","it":"","pt":"","tr":"","hi":"","bn":""}]
```

Comment: can you please specify ? with more code with output result.

Comment: `json_encode([$addresses])`?

Comment: You are using an Associative array. That array always outputs {}. A normal array outputs []